# Best Practices for handling simple "account balance" ledgers

Tags: accounting

I am working on a simple app to track account balances for users and companies.  I have a specific niche use for this (no need to get into the details of that).  However, as I am beginning to consider different methods to ensure accounts are always proper and up to date, I have a few options and am wondering what best practices are.

First, let's assume we have one table to track all transactions (both credits and debits).

What would be a better option?

1. Anytime a page is loaded that requires the account balance, the table is queried and all transactions are processed to calculate the latest balance.   Seems very resource intensive...
2. All functions add to this "transaction" table, but also update a running balance for each user anytime a Create/Update/Delete is made.  Then the transactions can be displayed when necessary, but only the balance is queried 99% of the time.
3. Perhaps #2 with a CRON job to validate that balance overnight, just to make sure nothing was missed?  Or this could run weekly, fo example.

Anything else I'm forgoing, or major considerations that could be required?

Thanks for the help.  For what it's worth, I'm using PHP/MYSQL but it shouldn't be relevant to this question/response.

Answer (score 0):

You could just keep a transaction table that has, in addition to the debit or credit amount,  an incrementing recID and the current balance. That way you could do this:

```
create table myTranstable ( recID IDType, customerID integer, acctBalance long, transactionAmount long)

begin a transaction

lock customerID

select max(recID),balance from myTransTable where customerID=thisCustomer

if(recID==NULL)
   createAZeroBalanceRecordFor(thisCustomer)
else
if( balance + thisTransactionAmount <0 )
  doSomethingAwfulTo(thisCustomer);
else
  insert into myTransTable values ( $newMaxId,customerID,balance+thisTransactionAmount,thisTransactionAmount )

unlock CustomerID 

end the transaction
```

This way you don't have to scan the whole table or do cron jobs etc. Sorry for the pseudocode, I don't know PHP or what database you have available.

Comment: MySQL - is it efficient to find the max(recID) in a huge table of transactions, vs. just pulling a single unique record from a user table to get the balance?